# Fetch domain name by passing name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch domain name by passing name.

consider following,

```
CREATE TABLE `mails` (
  `idmails` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mails` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mails
VALUES(1,'harishsng@gmail.com'),
(2,'harish.sn@m-tutor.com'),(3,'harishsn@yahoo.in');
```

When i pass 
Case 1: harishsng, result should be gmail,
Case 2: harish.sn it should be m-tutor.

How can i do it in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX` comes in handy here:

```
SELECT
    idmails,
    mails,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mails, '@', -1), '.', 1) AS domain
FROM mails;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for. You can use [substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
select substring_index(substring_index(mails,'.com',1), '@', -1 )  from mails where email like 'harishsng%'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT replace(replace(replace(mails,'harishsng',''),'@',''),'.com','') FROM bullet.mails where mails like '%harishsng%';

Comment: This is not at all a flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
select mails,substring_index(substring_index(mails,'@',-1),'.',1)
from mails
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answer are not appreciated and not much helpful.